# Simplify using a relation between variables in sympy

Tags: sympy

I want to do a calculation for general matrices from SU(2), i.e. I have a

```
a,b=symbols('a,b')
m=Matrix([[a,b],[-conjugate(b), conjugate(a)]])
```

and after some calculations i want sympy to simplify my result respecting that

```
abs(a)**2 + abs(b)**2 == 1.
```

Is there anyone with an idea how to tell sympy about this relation between a and b?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to solve the equation for one expression and replace it. In this case, replace `abs(a)**2` with `1 - abs(b)**2` (more generally, you can use `solve` to do this isolation for you).

So something like `expr.subs(abs(a)**2, 1 - abs(b)**2)`. You may also need to replace `a*conjugate(a)` with `abs(a)**2` (or rather, `conjugate(a)` with `abs(a)**2/a`) first to get things in terms of `abs`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! `simplify(expr.subs(a*conjugate(a), abs(a)**2).subs(b*conjugate(b), abs(b)**2).subs(abs(a)**2, 1 - abs(b)**2))` worked perfectly!